# How do I pass a post with a response parameter in JMeter using Groovy

Tags: ajax, groovy, jmeter

I am using JMeter to performance/load test our Reports page on our site.  I can use the recorder to get up to viewing the reports page.  That is fine.
I enter a search keyword "John" and this is an Ajax request.
I am aware I need to use the JSR223 sampler to achieve this part.

On executing the search on the reports page I inspect the Net\XHR tab from Firefox developer tools.

I can see the Post tab has the following data (I can see John near the end of the parameter if you scroll across):

```
7|0|12|http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore501/ClearCore/|322A1D708B0A3B67A22DF446A7A52581|com.company.clearcore.client.services.CCService|repSearch|java.lang.String/2004016611|org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.soapcon.DVSearchParams/3290294308|Regression_IE11_24042015|all_records|com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ArrayOfstring/3877610009|java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|java.lang.Integer/3438268394|john|1|2|3|4|3|5|5|6|7|8|6|9|10|0|0|0|11|786|11|1|12|
```

The Response tab has the following data:

```
//OK[3,45,2,1,["org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.soapcon.DVSearchResult/800921329","java.lang.Integer/3438268394","Do_Name_SOURCE_FIELDS"],0,7]
```

If i use the sample JSR223 Groovy code from http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter where can i insert the post & response parameters?

Does anyone have a sample code i could use to do this please?

Comment: The blazemeter example you linked is just using the apache HTTPClient to perform requests. Look for apache httpclient examples/tutorials for POST requests. For example, this one is in Java, but is still useful: http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `HttpGet` with `HttpPost` and it should work

Reference code below:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore501/ClearCore/");
List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramname1", "paramvalue1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramname2", "paramvalue2"));
...
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

For more information on Apache HTTPClient and some examples refer to [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) guide.

Also make sure that you properly enable Groovy scripting engine and follow best scripting practices. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for details on how to install groovy support and scripting tips and tricks.